# how can we show a pdf in a QnA maker as answer to a question?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I have PDF documents, that has lots of screenshots and very less text. How can I show the PDF itself directly, when a user asks for a particular question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the solution to this. There is a Link icon on the answers section in qnamaker.ai, where we can provide a link to the pdf, where pdf could be stored on a blob storage or any public location.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the document in question it sounds like QnA Maker is the wrong tool for the job.

The following is from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/overview/overview#what-is-a-knowledge-base):

> QnA Maker imports your content into a knowledge base of question and answer pairs.

QnA Maker **does not** perform OCR on the ingested documents. You could use the [Read API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text) which is part of the [Computer Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/overview) offering to OCR the document and extract text from the images, then input into QnA Maker.

Alternatively, you could manually update the QnA pair in question to include the link to the PDF using the markdown syntax outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format#supported-markdown-format).

e.g. `For more information, see product PDF which is available [here](https://<your-url-here>)`.